# MainActivity as return null data from SampleDataProvider.class

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

> I didn't get data item from SampleDataProvider.  It's return with null
>   list. Please kindly help.
>
> **MainActivity**
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
> TextView tvOut;
> ListView lOut;
> List<DataItem> dataItemList = SampleDataProvider.dataItemList;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     tvOut = findViewById(R.id.out);
>     tvOut.setText("");
>     for (DataItem dataItem : dataItemList) {
>          tvOut.append(dataItem.getItemName() + "\n");
>      }
>  } }
> ```

**SampleDataProvider**

```
public class SampleDataProvider {
public static List<DataItem> dataItemList;
public static Map<String, DataItem> dataItemMap;

private static void addItem(DataItem dataItem){
dataItemList.add(dataItem);
dataItemMap.put(dataItem.getItemId(),dataItem);
}
static {
        dataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataItemMap = new HashMap<>();
        addItem(new DataItem(null, "My menu Item", "a cateogry","a descriptoin", 1,9.95,"apple_pie.jpg"));
        addItem(new DataItem(null, "Quinoa Salmon Salad", "Salads","Our quinoa salad is served with quinoa, tomatoes, cucumber, scallions, and smoked salmon. Served with your choice of
    dressing.", 1, 12, "quinoa_salad.jpg"));
        } 
}
```

Comment: where is your addItem method ?

Comment: can you show us your DataItem class?

Comment: I just found my wrong code "addItem method" in DataItem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your assignment of the `dataItemList` in your main activity must also be static.

```
static List<DataItem> dataItemList = SampleDataProvider.dataItemList;
```

However this is not object-oriented!

Comment: Thank you sir, But It's still null list.

Comment: I just found my wrong code "addItem method" in DataItem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found my wrong code "addItem method" in DataItem.

```
private String itemId;
private String itemName;
private String description;
private String category;
private String sortPosition;
private String price;
private String image;
```

This code should be

```
private String itemId;
private String itemName;
private String description;
private String category;
private int sortPosition;
private double price;
private String image;
```

SmapleDataItem

```
addItem(new DataItem(null, "butthry", "description","category",1, 12, "images.jpg"));
```